# Auto-sizing a UILabel without setting an explicit height

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

How do I get a multi-line label to size itself? I don't want to set an explicit height for it but I do need to place it in view.

The way my app is built, we explicitly set frames and origins rather than using `NSLayoutConstraints`. It's a mature app so this isn't up for discussion.

I'd like to be able to give my UILabel an `origin` and a `width` and let it figure its own height out.

How can I do this? This is my playground code:

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 180))
view.backgroundColor = .white

let l = UILabel()
l.text = "this is a really long label that should wrap around and stuff. it should maybe wrap 2 or three times i dunno"
l.textColor = .black
l.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
l.numberOfLines = 0
l.textAlignment = .center
l.sizeToFit()

let margin: CGFloat = 60
view
view.addSubview(l)
l.frame = CGRect(x: margin, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width - (margin * 2), height: 100)
// I don't want to do this ^^
```

Comment: have you tried `intrinsicContentSize`? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622600-intrinsiccontentsize

Comment: Or have you tried Auto Layout?

Comment: @koen read the 2nd paragraph of my post please :)

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that :)

Comment: All good. No one reads. I know how it goes :)

Answer (score 0):

This may do what you want...

As requested, you want to set the `.origin` and `.width` of a `UILabel` and have it set its own `.height` based on the text.

```
class ZackLabel: UILabel {

    override public func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let h = sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: self.bounds.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        self.frame.size.height = h.height
    }

}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var testLabel: ZackLabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .yellow

        // instantiate a 300 x 180 UIView at 20, 80
        let myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 80, width: 300, height: 180))
        myView.backgroundColor = .white

        // instantiate a ZackLabel
        testLabel = ZackLabel()
        testLabel.text = "this is a really long label that should wrap around and stuff. it should maybe wrap 2 or three times i dunno"
        testLabel.textColor = .black
        testLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        testLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        testLabel.textAlignment = .center

        // set background color so we can see its frame
        testLabel.backgroundColor = .cyan

        let margin: CGFloat = 60

        // set label's origin
        testLabel.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: margin, y: 0)

        // set label's width (label will set its own height)
        testLabel.frame.size.width = myView.bounds.width - margin * 2

        // add the view
        view.addSubview(myView)

        // add the label to the view
        myView.addSubview(testLabel)

        // add a tap recognizer so we can change the label's text at run-time
        let rec = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapFunc(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(rec)
    }

    @objc func tapFunc(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
        testLabel.text = "This is dynamic text being set."
    }

}
```

Result (on an iPhone 8):

[image]

and, after tapping on the (yellow) view, dynamically changing the text:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

`label.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: <your required width>, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))`

This returns the labels needed size, growing infinitely in height, but fitted to your required width. I've occasionally noticed minor inaccuracies with this function (rounding error?), so I tend to bump the width and height by 1 just to be safe.

Answer (score -1):

`UILabel` comes with an intrinsic size that should be calculated based on the text and the label's `.font` property. You may need to add a margin to it...

```
var height = l.intrinsicContentSize.height
height += margin
l.frame = CGRect(x: margin, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width - (margin * 2), height: height)
```

Failing that, maybe you can try something like:

```
let size = CGSize(width: view.bounds.width - (margin * 2), height: 1000)
let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
var estimatedFrame = CGRect()
if let font = l.font {
    estimatedFrame = NSString(string: l.text).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font], context: nil)
}
//if you need a margin:
estimatedFrame.height += margin
l.frame = estimatedFrame
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Give your UILabel as a UIScrollview or UITableView cell subview.
2. Then you setup UILabel leading, tralling, top, bottom constrain.
3. If you give UITableview then set table view hight auto dynamic. If you give UIScrollview 
   just set UILabel bottom constrain priority low